# How to fetch Emails from child label in Gmail API?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I want to fetch emails from a specific label created by the user, I'm able to fetch emails for the custom labels but when I try to fetch emails for child label it's not working for me.

[image]

Here is my label hierarchy, I'm able to fetch mails from 'Test 1' and 'Test 2' labels, but when I try to fetch mails from 'Child Folder 1' label it always returns a blank array of emails.

Here is the API query that I'm using to fetch emails from 'Test 1' label.

https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=in:Test%201%20&maxResults=20

For 'Child Folder 1' label I have formed the URL like below.

https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=in:Test%201/Child%20Folder%201%20&maxResults=20

Gmail document reference : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to retrieve emails from a nested label using the GMail API

There are a couple of approaches to this.

Say I have these labels:

[image]

Each has a few messages in them.

#### Method 1

You could go to GET [`user.labels.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/list) which will return a list of all the labels. With the label `id` you can then go to [`user.messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) and make the request

```
https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?labelIds=[LABEL_ID]&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]'
```

#### Method 2

Using the query parameter, as you have done. The query is:

```
in:test/nested label
```

Which is URL encoded as

```
q=in%3Atest%2Fnested%20label
```

So the final request would be

```
https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=in%3Atest%2Fnested%20label&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]'
```

So perhaps your issue was that you didn't URL encode the `/` in the query as `%2F`

#### Reference

- [`user.labels.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/list)
- [`user.messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)